# I can't click the Revoke button in gray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't click the Revoke button in gray.Can anyone tell me the answer, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to add or edit any existing certificate?

Comment: This certificate is added to any of the provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

You are not permitted to revoke. Get `admin` permission from `agent` to revoke. Guess currently you are given with developer permission.

Comment: The reason was that ios Service not available because of maintenance activities, please try again after some time. it works fine Now. Thanks for your answer.